# React useState update not being called when calling parent function passed by props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to block clicks on UI element when they have already been selected, I'm using useState for this and 2 boolean variables which should alter the behavior of the handler functions for 'votes'.

On top of this useState boolean logic I'm also calling a parent function to update and sort the list in the parent object. If I don't call the parent function the useState logic works fine, as soon as I attempt both the boolean logic stops working for some reason.

Code in question:

Child element

```
const QuoteBubble = (props: Quote) =>{

    const [upArrowSelected, updateUpArrowSelected] = useState(false);
    const [downArrowSelected, updateDownArrowSelected] = useState(false);

        
    

    const upVote = (event: React.MouseEvent)=>{
        event.preventDefault();
        if(upArrowSelected){
            updateDownArrowSelected(false);
            updateUpArrowSelected(false);
            props.passVotes(props.votes - 1, props.quoteId);
            return;
        }
        updateDownArrowSelected(false);
        updateUpArrowSelected(true);
        props.passVotes(props.votes + 1, props.quoteId);
    }
    
    const downVote = (event: React.MouseEvent) =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        if(downArrowSelected){
            props.passVotes(props.votes + 1, props.quoteId);
            updateUpArrowSelected(false);
            updateDownArrowSelected(false);  
            return;
        }
        props.passVotes(props.votes - 1, props.quoteId);
        updateUpArrowSelected(false);
        updateDownArrowSelected(true);     
    }
    

    return(
        <Card variant="outlined" className='quote-bubble'>

            <div className='quote-text quote-box'>
            <a href='' className={`btn + ${upArrowSelected ? 'arrow-selected' : 'arrow-not-selected'}`} 
                   onClick={upVote}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSquareCaretUp} className='up-arrow'/></a>
                <h1>
                    {props.quote}
                </h1>
            </div>
                <div className='quote-text author-box'>
                <a href='' className={`btn + ${downArrowSelected ? 'arrow-selected' : 'arrow-not-selected'}`} 
                   onClick={downVote}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSquareCaretDown} className='down-arrow'/></a>
                <Chip label={props.votes} variant="outlined" className='votes-pill' />
                <p>
                    {props.author}
                </p>
                
                </div>
            
        </Card>
    )
```

Parent element

```
const QuoteList = (props: QuoteListProps) =>{

    const sortQuotes = (quotes: QuoteDataInput[]) => {
        quotes.sort((quoteA: QuoteDataInput, quoteB: QuoteDataInput) =>{
            return quoteB.votes - quoteA.votes;
        });
        props.setQuotes({quotes: [...quotes]});
        return quotes;
    }

    const GetVotes = (votes: number, id: number) =>{
        const updatedQuote = props.quoteList.find((quote) => quote.quoteId === id)
        if(updatedQuote){
            updatedQuote.votes = votes;
            props.setQuotes({quotes:[...props.quoteList, updatedQuote]});
        }
        sortQuotes(props.quoteList)
    }


    return(
        <ul className='quote-list'>
            {props.quoteList.map((quote: QuoteDataInput)=>(
                <li><QuoteBubble quote={quote.quote} author={quote.author} key={Math.random()} votes={quote.votes} passVotes={GetVotes} quoteId={quote.quoteId}/></li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

Yeah it's not the tidiest but I'm struggling to wrap my head around UI stuff as is

I expected both operations within "upVote" and "downVote" to occur. For some reason the call to "props.passVotes()" blocks the "updateDownArrowSelected()" and "updateUpArrowSelected()"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstand your question, but it appears to me that you want to keep track of the last vote and show this in the UI.

You can have 1 function for setting the vote and storing if the vote went up or down (+1 or -1). When you know if it was an upvote or a downvote, then you can highlight the UI from the last action.

```
const QuoteBubble = () => {
const [lastVote, setLastVote] = useState();

// Pass either 1 or -1 to function
const handleVote = (event: React.MouseEvent, value: number) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  props.passVotes(props.votes + value, props.quoteId);
  setLastVote(value);
}

  return (
    <>
      <button 
        onClick={(e) => handleVote(e, 1)}  
        className={`btn + ${lastVote === 1 ? 'arrow-selected' : 'arrow-not-selected'}`}>
          Vote up
      </button>
      <button 
        onClick={(e) => handleVote(e, -1)}
        className={`btn + ${lastVote === -1 ? 'arrow-selected' : 'arrow-not-selected'}`}>
          Vote down
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```